# Interesting Traffic and Management Traffic

Tags: traffic

I am trying to understand the types of traffic the NSOC deals with when updating devices across the gateways or even local to the NSOC.

Can anyone help me understand the types of traffic that there are?  I am only in change management so I don't deal directly with the gateways and performing updates.  I only look at the change request.

So, what does it mean by management traffic?  Interesting traffic is from devices trying to connect to another device such as a website, or file server...that is how I understand that, but I don't understand management traffic?  I have been told that it is traffic to "control" devices but I don't understand what that is?

I thought management traffic would be traffic coming from devices that are going to SIEM, Software Center, etc.

Would anyone be able to explain or give me a book or direction I could go to help me understand?

Comment: With NSOC you mean the National Security Operations Centre or a Network Security Operations Centre at a certain company? The last could also be a function of the SOC, only at very large multinationals they are seperated or ISPs maybe. And updating what kind of devices?

Answer (score 2):

To administer a network device, you usually have to connect to it.

Administer means:

- monitoring if the device is working correctly
- gathering reporting about its usage
- changing its configuration
- backuping regularly its configuration

That means you have some interfaces available on the devices to perform those tasks. Those are generally *not* a keyboard and a mouse but rather a web page or a CLI (command line interface) accessible via the network protocol SSH.

The management traffic is the traffic generated when performing those tasks.

It could be generated by the device itself, if configured to send logs, reports, etc... or from a management server that will regularly connect to the device, or by a human that connect to change the configuration.